# Meaning of "they write themselves out"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, vocabulary

It occurs regularly in Devils by Dostoevsky:

1.

> These talented gentlemen of the middling sort in the decline of their venerable years usually write themselves out in the most pitiful way [...].

2.

> It happens that a writer who has been for a long time credited with extraordinary profundity, betrays such insipidity in his fundamental ideas that no one regrets that he succeeded in writing himself out so soon.

Comment: Have you [looked it up](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/write+oneself+out)?

Comment: ***Write oneself out***. Exhaust one's energies or abilities by writing too much, as in *He's been doing a novel a year for ages, but now he's written himself out*. [Early 1800s] (AHD)